# testing android application with debug key

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-testing, digital-certificate

I want to give my app for testing. Is it necessary to sign it before dispatch?. Is it ok, if we sign app at time of release? As 'google say', for **'publishing'** your app it must be signed.

Basically, I think now I am using default debug key(I am developing in eclipse with help of emulator). If I direct mail only apk file which is in bin, can tester use it for testing? Or is it necessary to mail whole app?

Thank you.

Comment: An .apk cannot be run without the debug key. When you test it on emulator/device, the system generates a default Debug key. Quote:http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: However of-course you can mail the .apk from the bin because it is already signed and generated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can test the application without signing with a production key if you are mailing the apk. In case if you are uploading to the google play developer console or if you have inapp billing you need to sign the apk.